# javascript remove values from (inside) object literal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove an object from (inside?) a object literal. But I cant figure out why it doenst work.

```
var data= 
{
   "car": 3,
   "boat": 2
};

data.pop(); //should remove last one?
data.splice(1, 1); // removes element with index 1?
```

What am I doing wrong here? And is it posible you delete the item by name? Let say remove boat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since its a Object not an array, [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator) should work

Like this:

```
var data= 
{
   "car": 3,
   "boat": 2
};

alert(data["boat"]);
delete data["boat"];
alert(data["boat"]);
```

See it in action :
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/Gd34d/2/)

Answer (score 2):

`data` is not an array. The `pop` and `splice` methods operate on [integer index based arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
var data = [ 
    { "car": 3 },
    { "boat": 2 }
];

data.pop();
data.splice(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `delete`:

```
delete data.car;

> var data = { "car" : 3, "boat" : 2 }
> data
{ car: 3, boat: 2 }
> delete data.car;
> data
{ boat: 2 }
```

Comment: If the 'item' name is variable how would you use delete then?

Answer (score 1):

this is not an array

it only works on array

```
var data= 

    [  { "car": 3},{   "boat": 2}]
```